# VS2012 Xaml Designer: Where is the resource view?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, designer

I'm pleased to see that VS2012's Designer is much closer to Blend than the old one. One thing I still didn't find is Blend's "resource view":

[image]

VS2012 has something it calls resource view, but that is something different.

Without this, one can't reach templates other than by clicking through controls that use them.

Comment: And where the heck are the visual states? I started this project in 2012 because I was told that I wouldn't need Expression Blend. Now I'm stuck. Visual Studio 2012 doesn't do half the stuff expression blend does. It just happens to have a similar interface. Ahhh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I did some research and found this [preview](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30702). This is a stopgap until Update 2 released back in August. I haven't tried it yet. I'll edit my answer when I do. It seems that Update 2 of Visual Studio 2012 will include Blend support for Silverlight and WPF.

Here is [more information](http://blendinsider.com/technical/announcing-visual-studio-2012-update-2-ctp-2013-01-30/#more-1301) on the preview Update 2. This is what I get for switching to a Microsoft product too early. Hope this helps.

If anyone has any more information on this. Please let us know.

**Edits:**

The preview is basically a preview of Blend that will eventually expire.

The biggest thing I'm not clear on is whether this statement (from this KB article):

> "Blend for Visual Studio 2012 Support for Sketchflow, WPF, and Silverlight"

... means that Support for WPF and Silverlight will exist in Visual Studio itself or in another product.

Comment: Marking this as the answer as the respective functionality is probably simply not in Visual Studio itself, and this is the best plan b so far.

Comment: I still want more information. If anyone knows more about Update 2 and WPF and Silverlight support.

Comment: Did my marking you answer as accepted interfere with you bounty? I'm not exactly a stackoverflow veteran. Should I have waited?

Comment: I don't think so. Supposedly, you can add a bounty to a question that already has an answer. We'll see.

Comment: No answer. Bah! Just gotta wait and see. And hope the Update 2 provides what I need within the next 139 days.